# ¿Cómo guardo los datos de un gridview en una tabla (sql server)?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, asp.net, tablas, gridview

Tengo el siguiente GridView de la imagen, y deseo guardar los datos (información) de este en una tabla llamada (tbl_Compras), al pulsar el botón de "Terminar Compra". Con el fin de que el administrador de la página pueda ver las compras realizadas en la página en la base de datos.
[image: GridView]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.